# Base resistance in Tee Model

Tags: amplifier, bjt

This is about the 'TEE' Model in BJT small signal analysis on CB configuration. During the lectures, the one I learn is this model;

[image]

But in some books I found a different model with a base resistance.
[image]

If I do the calculations for common base configuration without the base resistance, I end up having a short circuit path from Base to ground. Even in examples this base resistance is not small so that we can neglect (Where the model uses a base resistance). Can anyone just say what is the importance in having a base resistance in this Tee model? :)

Comment: Ok, the first picture came from Sedra Smith. The latter? (Note that the first is a npn and the second is a pnp)

Comment: Next is from schaum's outline series!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger - I am not surprised that you feel confused. I only can recommend NOT to use the T-model because it is not a good basis for analyzing transistor circuits (for my opinion). Better use the hybrid- or y-parameter small-signal model.

Disadvantage of the T-model (first picture): **(1)** In common-emitter configuration it seems that the input resistance would be re (which is identical to 1/gm). However, that is not the case. Hence, there is a contradiction between formulas and equivalent signal diagram. **(2)** A similar problem does exist in common-base configuration. The base node must be grounded (output node of the current source) - nevertheless, only a part of the current (base current) goes into the grounded node. This is NOT in accordance with Kirchhoffs current law.

As far as the base resistance (second diagram) is concerned, I cannot answer your question without knowing the value (expression) of this part. The input resistance in common base configuration is 1/gm=re. Hence, rb=0. Of course, there is a small (ohmic) path resiostance between the base node and an inner point of the transistor body. But this value is always neglected.

Finally, I do not know any advantage of this (bloody) T-model if compared with all other equivalent circuit diagrams. The basic problem (and the cause of the inconsistencies) of the T-model is the fact that the transconductance gm is modeled as an ohmic (dynamic) resistance re=1/gm. But that`s not correct: It is not a resistive element. The transconductance connects the **input** voltage with the **output** current, and the ratio is NOT identical to a resistance with two nodes.

Comment: Thank you for this perfect explanation @LvW! One more thing to get clarified. In T model we're using r_e for the input resistance while in hybrid-pi model we're using r_pi. Other than in the T model, we wouldn't get to use r_e would we?

Comment: In the pi-model the role of r_e is taken over by the transconductance gm which is the controlling factor for the controlled current source at the output (remember: r_e=1/gm). That is the reason, I consider the pi-model much more correct and realistic than the T-model which has the mentioned deficiencies.

Comment: So we're setting r_pi as (1+b)r_e

Comment: Yes - that`s correct.

Comment: It was confusing to me! Now it's all clear! :) You're better than my lecturer!

Comment: @LvW I disagree with your comments about T model. T-model is in 100% equivalent to hybrid-pi and will give you exactly the same results as hybrid-pi. Also it is not true that r_e = 1/gm. In fact r_e = vbe/ie = Vt/Ie = alpha/gm. Look here http://images.slideplayer.com/13/4173510/slides/slide_37.jpg and try it yourself.

Comment: http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/5.6%20Small%20Signal%20Operation%20and%20Models/The%20Hybrid%20Pi%20and%20T%20Models%20lecture.pdf

Comment: G36, at first, you certainly will agree that it does not matter if r_e=1/gm or r_e=alpha/gm, don`t you? Secondly, I did not claim the T-model would be wrong. However, it creates some confusion (as for the OP) because of the reasons I have mentioned (input resistance in common-emitter; Kirchhoffs law). Look into the circuit (without the formulas) and tell me which input resistance you will see at the base node. Do you see what I mean? Where are the advantages of the T-model? Tell me only one single advantage!

Comment: By the way - I never trust any anonym "handouts" to be found anywhere in the internet (who is the author?)